# How to match a string in php which contains an https url with a fixed number of alphanumeric characters?

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that looks like:

```
"res":"https://my.site.com/image/I/fj23l6j2lgk_AM1200_.jpg"
```

My bash regex is (if we let the above equal to `$str`):

```
echo $str | grep -oE "\"res\":\"https://my.site.com/image/I/[[:alnum:]]{11}._[a-zA-Z0-9_]*_.jpg\"" \
| grep -oE "my.site.com/image/I/[[:alnum:]]{11}._[a-zA-Z0-9_]*_.jpg" | head -1
```

which cleanly extracts out `https://my.site.com/image/I/fj23l6j2lgk_AM1200_.jpg`.

In PHP, I am unsure if an equivalent can exist to what I have above. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: The same would work in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you wish to **validate** that the qualifying url is wrapped in double quotes and is preceded by `"res":`, **then** you want to **extract** the url only.

A lookbehind at the start and a lookahead at the end will validate the exact full string.

Dots must be escaped to be treated as string literals.

You had an extra dot before your underscore that I don't believe you want to keep.

You don't need to escape forward slashes if you use non-slash characters as pattern delimiters (I'll use `~`).

`[a-zA-Z0-9_]` is more concisely written as `\w`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/rM3ga))

```
$string = '"res":"https://my.site.com/image/I/fj23l6j2lgk_AM1200_.jpg"';

echo preg_match('~(?<=^"res":")https://my\.site\.com/image/I/[a-zA-z\d]{11}_\w*_\.jpg(?="$)~', $string, $out) ? $out[0] : 'no match';
```

Output:

```
https://my.site.com/image/I/fj23l6j2lgk_AM1200_.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to escape all the `/` and `.` in your regex, and it's fine. I also removed a dot near the end.

```
my\.site\.com\/image\/I\/[[:alnum:]]{11}_[a-zA-Z0-9_]*_\.jpg
```

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/rGyTQ0/1).

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP , you can pick it by:

```
$subject = '"res":"https://my.site.com/image/I/fj23l6j2lgk_AM1200_.jpg"';
$regex = '/https:\/\/my\.site\.com\/image\/I\/[[:alnum:]]{11}_[a-zA-Z0-9_]*_.jpg/'
preg_match($regex , $subject , $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

The output :

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(51) "https://my.site.com/image/I/fj23l6j2lgk_AM1200_.jpg"
}
```